# Vectorized creation of an array of diagonal square arrays from a liner array in Numpy or Tensorflow

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, vectorization

I have an array of shape `[batch_size, N]`, for example:

```
[[1  2]
 [3  4]
 [5  6]]
```

and I need to create a 3 indices array with shape `[batch_size, N, N]` where for every `batch` I have a `N x N` diagonal matrix, where diagonals are taken by the corresponding `batch` element, for example in this case, In this simple case, the result I am looking for is:

```
[
  [[1,0],[0,2]],
  [[3,0],[0,4]],
  [[5,0],[0,6]],
]
```

How can I make this operation without for loops and exploting vectorization? I guess it is an extension of dimension, but I cannot find the correct function to do this.
(I need it as I am working with tensorflow and prototyping with numpy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it in tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
A = [[1,2],[3 ,4],[5,6]]
B = tf.matrix_diag(A)
print(B.eval(session=tf.Session()))
[[[1 0]
  [0 2]]

 [[3 0]
  [0 4]]

 [[5 0]
  [0 6]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) with an element-wise product with [`np.eye`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html)

```
a = np.array([[1,  2],
              [3,  4],
              [5, 6]])
N = a.shape[1]
a = np.expand_dims(a, axis=1)
a*np.eye(N)

array([[[1., 0.],
       [0., 2.]],

      [[3., 0.],
       [0., 4.]],

      [[5., 0.],
       [0., 6.]]])
```

#### Explanation

`np.expand_dims(a, axis=1)` adds a new axis to `a`, which will now be a `(3, 1, 2)` ndarray:

```
array([[[1, 2]],

       [[3, 4]],

       [[5, 6]]])
```

You can now multiply this array with a size `N` identity matrix, which you can generate with [`np.eye`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html):

```
np.eye(N)
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

Which will yield the desired output:

```
a*np.eye(N)

array([[[1., 0.],
        [0., 2.]],

       [[3., 0.],
        [0., 4.]],

       [[5., 0.],
        [0., 6.]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

Here's a vectorized one with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for input array, `a` -

```
# Initialize o/p array
out = np.zeros(a.shape + (a.shape[1],),dtype=a.dtype)

# Get diagonal view and assign into it input array values
diag = np.einsum('ijj->ij',out)
diag[:] = a
```

**Approach #2**

Another based on slicing for assignment -

```
m,n = a.shape
out = np.zeros((m,n,n),dtype=a.dtype)
out.reshape(-1,n**2)[...,::n+1] = a
```

Answer (score 1):

Yu can use [`numpy.diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html)

```
m = [[1, 2],
 [3, 4],
 [5, 6]]

[np.diag(b) for b in m]
```

---

**EDIT** The following plot shows the average execution time for the solution above (solid line), and compared it against @Divakar's (dashed line) for different batch-sizes and different matrix sizes

[image]

I don't believe you get much of an improvement, but this is just based on this simple metric

Comment: I agree this is the simplest solution, but I was wondering whether through functions like `einsum` someone would make it highly vectorized and in one single line.

Comment: an other  difference is that your output is a list, not an array, so not good for further vectored computations.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want a function that does the opposite of/reverses `np.block(..)`

I needed the same thing, so I wrote this little function:

```
def split_blocks(x, m=2, n=2):
    """
    Reverse the action of np.block(..)

    >>> x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (2, 18, 20))
    >>> assert (np.block(split_blocks(x, 3, 4)) == x).all()

    :param x: (.., M, N) input matrix to split into blocks
    :param m: number of row splits
    :param n: number of column, splits
    :return:
    """
    x = np.array(x, copy=False)
    nd = x.ndim
    *shape, nr, nc = x.shape
    return list(map(list, x.reshape((*shape, m, nr//m, n, nc//n)).transpose(nd-2, nd, *range(nd-2), nd-1, nd+1)))
```